# after upgrading app to iOS9 it started to crash app "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue"

Tags: ios9

i have upgraded my xcode to 7.0 from 6.4 and iOS9 to my iPhone6 plus. 
after that my app is started crashing due to memory pressure.
I have used many third party libraries : 
SMTextView,
PFHComposeBarView,
MDRadialProgressView,
FHSTwitterEngine,
KLSwitch,
YLProgressBar,
IQKeyboardManager,
SDWebImageCache and many more..
beacuse i  need all this functionality in my app.
it was working fine in iOS8 with xcode6.4
but in iOS9 its not working continuosly throwing memory pressure issue

i have removed all third- party one by one and checked what is creating issue

but no luck

any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Use the Instruments utility and choose its Allocations template.  That should allow you to see which objects are taking up most space (and whether they're still taking space when not needed).